# Powershell Renaming Camera Pics & Vids with Appended number

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have tried to make a quick script in Powershell to rename camera pics & vids in a folder with a preferred naming convention:

(Last write time (yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_) + (file number) + (file extension)

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

$inc_pics = "*.jpg","*.png","*.bmp","*.jpeg","*.heic"
$inc_vids = "*.mp4","*.avi","*.mpg","*.mpeg","*.mov"

$included = $inc_pics+$inc_vids

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File -Include $included


$files


$x=1

if ($files.Count -gt 99)

    {

    $d = "{0:D3}"

    }

    else 

        {

        $d = "{0:D2}"

        }

cls
Write-Host "`n---------------------"
Write-Host "-- Renaming files: --"
Write-Host "---------------------`n`n"

foreach ($file in $files)

{

  $newname = ( "{0}{1}{2}" -f $file.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_'),($d -f ($x)), $file.Extension )

  Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newname
  
  Write-Host `t $file.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow -nonewline ; Write-Host "   is now   " -ForegroundColor White -nonewline; Write-Host $newname -ForegroundColor Green -nonewline ;
  Write-Host `n

  $x++
 
}


Read-Host "`nPress Enter to continue"

sleep 1
```

The basic script works but the appending of number isn't quite right in the test directory. I am expecting for example:

20171210_162727_01.jpg

20171210_162728_02.jpg

20171210_162729_03.mp4

20171210_162730_04.mp4

20171210_162731_05.jpg

But am getting:

20171210_162727_01.jpg

20171210_162728_02.jpg

20171210_162729_04.mp4

20171210_162730_05.mp4

20171210_162731_03.jpg

It's probably something obvious but I'm not seeing what is causing it. There doesn't appear to be a pattern between directories, however if repeated multiple times on a reverted directory the results are always the same

This is mainly done to prevent duplicate filenames (where multiple pictures are taken within a second of each other, I suppose another way would be to add a (1),(2) at the end (my phone does this for normal items and 001,002 etc. for burst pics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your intent is to base the sequence numbering on the chronological order implied by the files' last-write timestamp.

Therefore, replace:

```
foreach ($file in $files)
```

with:

```
foreach ($file in $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime)
```

That is, use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) to sort the file-info objects ([`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo)) emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) by their [`.LastWriteTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo.LastWriteTime) property values.

Comment: Simple as that! 

I was wondering what order it was putting them in as, works perfectly thanks